Como usar uma env dentro de um yml, especificamente Coveralls + TravisCi + Jest
Tenho um arquivo chamado .coveralls.yml preciso dele para passar o token do repositório do Github no momento que o TravisCi faz o build da aplicação em React + vite + Ts, ou seja, Nodejs.
.coveralls.yml
service_name: travis-ci
repo_token: yNj4Y********

O comando que é rodado no momento do build do travisCi é esse test:coveralls
package.json
"scripts": {
 ...
"test": "jest --passWithNoTests",
"test:ci": "npm test -- --coverage",
"test:coveralls": "npm run test:ci && coveralls < coverage/lcov.info"
},

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, o travis faz o build, executa os testes e manda para o coveralls, mas o problema é que estou tendo que passar publicamente esse token para o meu arquivo .coveralls.yml, ou seja, o token fica exposto para todos. Com isso, gostaria de saber se é possivel passar esse token para uma env e dela passar para o .coveralls.yml ou que seja de outra maneira.
Cheguei olhar a documentação do coveralls, mas não consegui compreender muito como eu poderia deixar esse token escondido.
Possíveis soluções que tentei fazer e que não deram certo
.env
COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN=yNj4Y********

.coveralls.yml
repo_token:${COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN}

e
 repo_token:$COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN

E sim necessariamente preciso desse token, pois, se eu não passar ele aponta para esse erro:

C:\Users\Pedro\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\tdd-clean-architecture-solid\node_modules\coveralls\bin\coveralls.js:19
throw err;
^
Bad response: 422 {"message":"Couldn't find a repository matching this job.","error":true}
(Use 'node --trace-uncaught ...' to show where the exception was thrown)

Arquivo pipeline do travisCi
.travis.yml
language: node_js
node_js: 
  - 17.9

cache: npm

install:
  - npm install

script:
  - eslint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'
  - npm run test:coveralls


Vc configurou a env no travisCI?

@CmteCardeal sim, e infelizmente não foi :/ cheguei a testar localmente colocando a .env local e também não foi

@Pedrohvfernandes isso está executando em uma pipeline? tipo github actions?

@Danizavtz Isso, só que no lugar do github actions, estou usando o travisCi

cade o script que executa a pipeline (o shell script) que tem as "tasks"?

Mil perdões @Danizavtz agora que eu vi que não coloquei na pergunta o arquivo do travisCi. Mas enfim, editei a pergunta e já coloquei as devidas informações.

rpz, eu já fiz isso uma vez, posso explicar, existem maneiras seguras de guardar passar esse token no travis-ci? tipo como é passado no github-actions? tipo o que fez aqui? repo_token:${COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN}

Então, vamos contextualizar pra ficar mais claro. No caso eu tentei fazer o seguinte, crie um .env com uma variável de ambiente COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN e tentei passa-la no arquivo .coveralls.yml como é feito em um yml de um docker da vida, so que não pegou kkkkkkkkk.

Mas agora você falando do github actions, lembrei que por la tem a questão de secrets, e com isso tentei algo. Fui no repo em secrets e criei obviamente uma secret com o nome REPO_TOKEN, passei para o coveralls.yml da seguinte maneira: repo_token: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}, com isso, após o travisCi terminar o build da aplicação, miraculosamente ele está conseguindo enviar o  lcov.info para o coveralls através desse secret que criei.
Mas caso você tenha outra solução em mente, estou disposto a ver

pois é, era justamente isso que eu ia sugerir... porém como não possuo um travisci, não tenho como testar... mas basicamente essa seria a minha ideia...

Show, perfeito então. Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Danizavtz abriu a minha mente kkkkkkkk

q nd, fui apenas o pato de borracha...

Não teria como te avaliar não ?

opa, o que pode ser feito é tu mesmo responder tua pergunta com a tua solução. :-), veja essa publicação que explica o fluxo e como funciona o stackoverflow.

Show, mais uma vez muito obrigado Deniza ;)

Enfim foi achado a solução através da comunidade para o problema em si.
Primeiro antes de tudo, tenha em mente em ter feito um pipeline.yml na raiz do projeto, como por exemplo .coveralls.yml onde nele será colocado o token do repositório que está no coveralls.io.
Para achar o token, é bem simples, basta ir no coveralls.io, depois dentro do repositório que você deu permissão para o coveralls analisar:

Com o token em mãos, a solução é bem simples. Em seu repositório do GitHub indo em settings, depois em secrets and variables clicando em Actions, clicando na opção New Repository Secrets ira aparecer dois campos, um para o nome(Name) e o outro para colocar o token(secret) que vem do coveralls. Ao preencher basta colocar essa secret no arquivo de pipeline citado anteriormente(.coveralls.yml) passando ${{ secrets.NOME_DA_SECRET }}
Ex dentro do github actions:

Ex dentro do .coveralls.yml após criar a secret no github actions:
service_name: travis-ci
repo_token: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}

Essa secret vai ser pega no momento em que rodar em um sistema de CI/CD, como por exemplo o próprio github actions ou um travisCi da vida, quando um dos dois forem executar as devidas tasks das suas pipelines(ex: .travis.yml), como build, testes... ao rodarem a task que possui o comando do coveralls, ele irá utilizar a pipeline .coveralls.yml que tem a secret que foi colocada no github actions, ao pegar o token, ele envia os dados de informação dos testes para o coveralls.
